# JS best practice List of Objects vs Array vs Value-Pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am working on a learning project (basically I am building a web site based on Node-Express to learn Node-Express).
I need to make a 'menu', and I am struggling finding the best way to represent it in JSON (and then to use in a HTML table).
the options I thought of are:

```
{"menu" : [{"coffee": 2.00}, {"juice": 3.50}, {"smoothy": 4.00}]} 

{"menu" : {"coffee": 2.00, "juice": 3.50, "smoothy": 4.00}}

{"menu" : [{"item": "coffee", "price": 2.00}, {"item": "juice", "price": 3.50}, {"item": "smooth", "price": 4.00} ]}
```

I found a way to process all the above but I would like to understand which one is the best option for my scenario (and possibly why the others are not).

Comment: First is invalid syntax. Second is difficult to iterate when there will be multiple records. Third is more suitable.

Comment: Third option is best because you will have easy access to both item as well as its price, in first you can pass a key in array so its invalid syntax and second could work to.@GiovanniVigorelli

Comment: Yeah.. forgot {}, first option would be:
{"menu" : [{"coffee": 2.00}, {"juice": 3.50}, {"smoothy": 4.00}]}

Comment: *I found a way to parse all the above* Please do not misuse the term "parse". "Parse" means to analyze a string according to a particular grammar, and transform it into some kind of processable reprresentation. That's not what you mean here. You simply mean "access" or "retrieve from" or "iterate over" or "process" or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var menu = {"coffee": 2.00, "juice": 3.50, "smoothy": 4.00}

$(function() {
   //FILTER example
   var filter =  _.pick(menu, function(num){ return num % 2 == 0; });
   console.log(filter)
})
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I would opt for this:-

```
var menu = {"coffee": 2.00, "juice": 3.50, "smoothy": 4.00}
```

I have many reasons :-

- Easy to maintain (as simple key-value pair)
- Easy to Iterate over
- Easy for retrieve value according to item name
- Easy for filtering (like you want to filter according to price may be simple or may be price range)

Comment: I second this way.

Comment: What if you want them to be ordered? With regard to filtering, could you provide a quick example of filtering by price range so we all can see how easy it is?

Answer (score 1):

The third one is more semantic and friendly. you can easily iterate through them and use `item` for other operations like, say `if (item == something)`, and it looks more readable.